# Meteor - How to exclude certain paths from being crawled?

Tags: javascript, meteor, web-crawler, single-page-application, hashbang

In Meteor, I have installed the [`spiderable`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spiderable) package, which allows the application to be crawled by search engines. However, I want to exclude certain paths from being crawled.

For example, `example.com/abc/[path]` should **not** be crawled, whereas `example.com/[path]` should be.

I am unsure of how to do this. One guess is to include a `robots.txt` in the `/public` directory, and use regex as described [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61261/28919). However, the url doesn't contain the `#!` as it did in this question. Is that relevant?

---

My current implementation is a bit more complicated, and it's based on the following quote from the package's `README.md`:

> In order to have links between multiple pages on a site visible to
>   spiders, apps must use real links (eg ) rather than
>   simply re-rendering portions of the page when an element is clicked.

At the moment, when the page is rendered, I test whether there's a `/abc` in the root of the path, and then set a persistent session variable. This allows me to make all paths in my pages' links **not** contain the `/abc` prefix. When a link is clicked, it will check whether the session variable is set and append to the path in an `onBeforeAction()` function, which allows the right template to be rendered. In doing so, I am *hoping* those links won't be visible to the spider, but I am unsure of the reliability of such a method.

---

**tl;dr - How to exclude certain paths from being crawled in Meteor?**

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you're doing with the folders you don't want crawled. If they're just going to be used on the server side, you can use the `/private/` folder. If you want them accessible, but uncrawlable, you can build in access to folders with a `/.period/` in them, which makes them invisible to Meteor, but you can access via the `connectHandlers` and `webApp` properties similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019570/cant-view-new-files-in-meteors-public-directory/28020655#28020655).

If you want them to be processed by Meteor as normal (e.g. javascript files) but then be inaccessible to the spiderable package, I'd suggest asking in [meteor-core](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/meteor-core).