# Can't view new files in meteors public directory

Tags: javascript, meteor, upload, public

When a meteor app gets compiled (`meteor build app`), the public directory `becomes \programs\web.browser\app` All files which were in the development public directory `\public` are now accessible with `http://domain.tld/file-in-public-directory.jpg`

When I put a new file into the compiled public directory and try to view it in the browser, I get an error, which says that Meteor does not have a route for that url. When I do this in the development public directory it works flawless, but not in the compiled (`meteor build app`).

I need this, because I want to upload new files in that directory.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you'll have to tweak it a little bit, but there's a way you can access pretty much any folder you want, especially for static files, by using the low level `connectHandlers` object.

Here is an example where you have a folder named .images (hidden from the Meteor auto-refresh), which serves images whenever a request is made to http://[yoursiteURL]/images/...

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var re = /^\/images\/(.*)$/.exec(req.url);
  if (re !== null) {   
    var filePath = process.env.PWD 
    + '/.images/' 
    + re[1];
    var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, data);
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image'
    });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  } else {  
    next();
  }
});
```

You're using a regular expression to find out if the incoming request is trying to access /images/. If it is, we're going to send the image with the appropriate headers, using `res.write()`

Two things of note:

1- you don't have to use anything special (no packages, etc) to use the `Npm.require('fs')` because it's built in and usable.

2- using `fs.readFileSync` is a bit of a hack, and is blocking. You'll want to tweak that for a performant, production app.

Hope this helps!   A bit more information on `connectHandlers` can be found [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp).

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see folks out there trying meteor.  It's great stuff - but at the same time, it does seem complicated.  What really helped me so much is using this app: [metoer-kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com/getting_started).  I now use it alongside when working on my projects.